# VBA Blank Cells offsetting data when copying

Tags: vba, if-statement, statements

I'm trying to write a code that extracts data using IF statements and scans through rows of data, if it has data, copy it and all relevant data, if it doesn't do nothing.

My current plan is this

1. If cell X has data copy that data and all relevant data to master sheet after latest entry. Then go to the next row down and do the same.
2. Create a code offsets the entire macro by a certain amount of columns (Quarters column makes this difficult since the data i'm extracting is in months)
3. Create a macro that takes data from all the tabs after the master sheet tab which is not the first worksheet tab.

Here is my excel file. Not sure if there a place to upload on stackoverflow but here it is on send space. This is the exact format i get my data in. This is a small piece of a much larger work file that contains 60+ tabs of data.
http://www.sendspace.com/file/3irz5n

Here is my code so far which doesn't work. I think i have some of the syntax wrong.

EDIT: Fixed a couple problems. The code runs fine except this one problem.

Here is my current code. I'm having problems with Blank cells in my source data. When there's a blank cell it doesn't copy anything and offsets my data in my master sheet. For instance if the data in column A1 is 200, A2 is 300. The data that suppose to be in B2 goes to B1 Because B1 was Blank. The problem code starts at 'Copy cell to mastersheet

```
Sub Test()

Dim imaxrow As Double
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Worksheets
    'Need to find a way to take data from sheets AFTER macro test sheet
    If ws.Name <> "Macro Test Sheet" Then
    'Rows of data to be extracted
    imaxrow = 22 'Max rows
    'Use to offset columns to next dataset
        For Each E In Array(0, 11)
        'Starting row to copy data
        For iRow = 10 To imaxrow
            If ws.Cells(iRow, 21).Value = "" Then
                'Nothing in this cell.
                'Do nothing.
                Else
                ' Copy Cell data to mastersheet
                ws.Cells(iRow, 21 + E).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("macro test sheet").Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                ws.Cells(iRow, 22 + E).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("macro test sheet").Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                ws.Cells(iRow, 23 + E).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("macro test sheet").Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                ws.Cells(iRow, 24 + E).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("macro test sheet").Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                ws.Cells(iRow, 4).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("macro test sheet").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                ws.Cells(iRow, 3).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("macro test sheet").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                ws.Cells(5, 1).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("macro test sheet").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                ws.Cells(6, 21 + E).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("macro test sheet").Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                ws.Cells(7, 21 + E).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("macro test sheet").Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            End If
        Next iRow
        Next E
     End If
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Thank you again for the help and tips.

Answer (score 0):

"I think i have some of the syntax wrong" is not helpful. You need to tell us the error message you receive and the line that this error refers to.

But this is probably wrong:

```
WS.Range(.Cells(10, 7))
```

unless `.Cells(10, 7)` happens to contain a cell address.

If you want further assistance you need to ask a specific question.

**Added**

```
If Cells(10, 7) = "" Then
```

I assume this should be looking in the "Macro Test Sheet" so this should also be preceded by a dot, otherwise it is looking in whatever is currently the ActiveSheet.

Comment: The code runs with no error but no information is pulled into the mastersheet. What I want is to check if cell 10,7 has information, if it does extract that information and other relevant information and paste it into the mastersheet in the specific rolls I Outlined.